# ReactJS app works fine running with "npm start" but when i build the the app using "npm run build" it doesn't link with backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, react-fullstack

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAM1H.png)

This error has been showing in my console from chrome.
Also note that i am using axios to fetch data from backend

.

I used "proxy": "http://localhost:8800/api" in my package.json in reactJS project and also tried to add cors in the NodeJS

But it really didn't changed the access link!

Comment: You have to setup a local server to use your app. Opening file with a browser is not an option

Comment: Including a direct link in the axios.get("http://localhost:8800/api/____") might solve the issue.

though this shouldn't be the answer I assume!

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `fetch` disallows requests to URLs whose scheme is `file`. What are you actually trying to do? Surely, you want to send a request to some `https` (or perhaps `http`) URL.